# return all lines that match String1 in a file after the last matching String2 in the same file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, sh

I figured out how to get the line number of the last matching word in the file :

```
cat -n textfile.txt | grep " b " | tail -1 |  cut -f 1
```

It gave me the value of 1787. So, I passed it manually to the sed command to search for the lines that contains the sentence "blades are down" after that line number and it returned all the lines successfully

```
sed -n '1787,$s/blades are down/&/p' myfile.txt
```

Is there a way that I can pass the line number from the first command to the second one through a variable or a file so I can but them in the script to be executed automatically ?

Thank you.

Comment: All of your Solutions are Great!! Thank you all,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by just connecting your two commands with xargs. 'xargs -I %' allows you to take the stdin from a previous command and place it whenever you want in the next command. The '%' is where your '1787' will be written:

```
cat -n textfile.txt | grep " b " | tail -1 |  cut -f 1 |  xargs -I % sed -n %',$s/blades are down/&/p' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Great! thatnk you very much.
now the ouput is in the form :
Line1
Line2

what should I add to that command so it looks like (print the word warning before the outputs)
warning:line1
warning:line2
Thanks

Comment: @user3254640: Replace the `sed` command with the following: `sed -n 's/^.*blades are down.*$/warning: &/p'` - the modified regex will match the *entire* line and therefore report it in `&`, allowing you to prepend the desired string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this is giving me results before that line number that was passed by the first command in addition to the last two lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- command substitution to capture the result of the first command in a variable.
- simple string concatenation to use the variable in your `sed` comand

```
startLine=$(grep -n ' b ' textfile.txt | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f1)

sed -n ${startLine}',$s/blades are down/&/p' myfile.txt
```

You don't strictly need the intermediate variable - you could simply use:

```
sed $(grep -n ' b ' textfile.txt | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f1)',$s/blades are down/&/p' myfile.txt`
```

but it may make sense to do error checking on the result of the command substitution first.

Note that I've streamlined the first command by using `grep`'s `-n` option, which puts the line number separated with `:` before each match.

Answer (score 0):

First we can get "half" of the file after the last match of string2, then you can use `grep` to match all the string1

```
tac your_file | awk '{ if (match($0, "string2")) { exit ; } else {print;} }' | \
  grep "string1"
```

but the order is reversed if you don't care about the order. But if you do care, just add another `tac` at the end with a pipe `|`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/\n/ba;/ b /h;//!H;$!d;x;//!d;s/$/\n/;:a;/\`.*blades are down.*$/MP;D' file
```

This reads through the file storing all lines following the last match of the first string (`" b "`) in the hold space.

At the end of file, it swaps to the hold space, checks that it does indeed have at least one match, then prints out those lines that match the second string (`"blades are down"`).

N.B. it makes the end case (`/\n/`) possible by adding a new line to the end of the hold space, which will eventually be thrown away. This also caters for the last line edge condition.